# How to use a laptop as a second monitor for another laptop in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors

Both laptops run Ubuntu. One of them runs Ubuntu 16.04 and the other runs Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Have a look in to this link http://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor

Comment: @ElderGeek I missed that one... I'll delete my comment. Thank you :)

Comment: Synergy might be your best bet

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to try [Synergy.](https://symless.com/synergy/) Note that this is a commercial product that it appears must be purchased and you could likely obtain a used 2nd screen for what they are asking (~$20). I personally have not tried it, and have no affiliation, nor experience with the company offering it. It seems that they do however have versions for Linux, Mac OSX, and Windows so it's pretty platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a laptop as a second monitor because you have no input to go to your output. A tv or second screen is an ex. of an input device.

Comment: A screen is an output, the computer outputs information to the screen, an input would be a key board. The issue is a laptop has no HDMI input port, so cannot output to the screen. You are right in principal but this is a little backwards.

Comment: My bad. But yeah that's it